# invalid Url generated for POST action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I think there is a problem with URL generation.

Assuming that we have the following controller:

```
[Route("[action]")]
public class Home : Controller
{
    [Route("/")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{number}")]
    public IActionResult Edit(int number)
    {
        
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The index view generated correct link to Edit action:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-all-route-data='new Dictionary<string, string>{{"number", "11"}}'>GO TO EDIT</a>
```

Which is `/Edit/11`.

But then in the edit view I am trying to create a form that should post to the same action, but there is no route parameter. So, the URL should be just `/Edit`. Instead, I get `/Edit/11` which does not reach appropriate action on the controller. I am generating forms in two ways and the result is the same:

```
<div>
    <form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    }
</div>
```

What is more, changing POST route template to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("something")]
    public IActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Causes link generated for GET to be `http://localhost:5253/Edit/something?number=11` which is wrong.

To me, it looks like a bug, but I might have overlooked something. Could you please help me understand this behavior? All endpoints are registered correctly. Is there route precedence involved? If so, then how because those action methods react to separate verbs... I am confused.

Please find project under this link: https://blindsend.io#5m4QCCyXKdchLEos4M1ang;GnFBHbs2xAap6QzxJadwFw==

Comment: POST does not modify the URL (that would be a GET).  You probably want to redirect in your Post method instead of returning "View()"

Comment: @pcalkins contents of the POST method are only for demonstration of the problem. The core of the issue is how URLs are generated.

Comment: Well, it will obviously work if the route template for GET and POST are the same. But IMO this should also work just fine...

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood... but I think your asp-action="Edit" line should POST to the same page and to the method named "Edit".  Is that not happening?  If you need the id, you should include that as a hidden field in the form.  POSTed parameters come from the body of the request, not the URL.

Comment: @pcalkins i omitted it for simplicity, post should accept model, for example:

[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(Model model)
    {
        return View();
    }

The thing is that we have two methods that are not the same and both have different route template. Looks like this is not supported and actions should have the same URL template but no exception is thrown upon initialization.

Comment: I see what you're getting at here... but I think it's enough to just have the  [HttpPost] there... that's equivalent to a different route.  (parameters are passed through the body of the request anyway since it's a POST...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a test with your sample code, and everything worked well after I comment `[Route("{number}")]`.

When we have `[Route("{number}")]` before the Get action method, the request to the Controller will be `https://localhost:7131/Edit/11`, if we comment this attribute, the request will be `https://localhost:7131/Edit?number=11`.

The error happened at the form submit operation, and for POST action `public IActionResult Edit()`, the correct request URL should be `POST https://localhost:7131/Edit`, but when the URL in the browser is `https://localhost:7131/Edit/11` and do the form submit, the submit request will be like below and the issue happened.

[image]

About the error 405, that means the URL is correct but method is not allowed, in this issue, the "not allowed" points to the Url Routing, to **fix the issue**, we can comment `[Route("{number}")]` or add `[Route("{number}")]` to the POST action.

Let's go back to the normal behavior, see [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0) here. The default route mapping defined as `pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");` and when the Edit Get request become `Movies/Edit/5` we need to have Movie Controller with Get action `public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)`, the `id`  is the parameter instead of a route attribute. That's why I say I comment `[Route("{number}")]` at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, exactly. so, it looks like a bug or inconsistency. If this is not desired setup, there should be an exception during initialization of the app.

Comment: per my understanding, it shouldn't be a bug. routing for MVC app or api app should obey the settings/definition which should obey how asp.net core required. Or in other words, we should write like what offical document demonstrating.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can find aspnet team answer in this question on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47375#issuecomment-1481063287